# Gram-Schmidt orthogonality

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, gram-schmidt

Given a vector $v = (1,2,−1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Use the Gram-Schmidt process to ﬁnd two vectors $v_1$ and $v_2$ such that $\{v,v_1,v_2\}$ is an orthogonal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you please let us know what you have tried so far? People are more likely to help you if you show us your effort first.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Start with the basis

- $v=(1,2,-1)$
- $v_1=(1,0,1)$
- $u_2=(0,1,0)$

and apply the algorithm to obtain an orthogonal basis.

See also the related

- [Gram Schmidt-The arts behind it](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2589301/505767)
- [Find orthonormal vectors for given vectors using Gram-Schmidt](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2585374/505767)
- [Is there a more convenient method for converting a base to be orthogonal than Gram Schmidt?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2653008/505767)

Comment: can you please elaborate the solution?

Comment: @AbhishekGoswami I want only give a hint, you need to proceed by yourself form here. Are you aware how GS works?

Comment: nope, I have no Idea how it works.

Comment: @AbhishekGoswami I've added some other OP as reference, you can find many other of them here on MSE. Take also a look to your reference notes or on the web. If you show your work I'll take a look to it. Bye

Comment: @AbhishekGoswami Note that with the given basis indicated in the answer v and $v_1$ are already orthogonal then it suffices that you orthogonalize $u_2$ to $v_2$.