# Find an orthogonal basis for V

Tags: linear-algebra, gram-schmidt

Let V be the three dimensional subspace of $$R^{4}$$ defined by
the equation
$$x_{1} − 2x_{2} + 3x_{3} − 4x_{4} = 0.$$
Find an orthonormal basis for V .

I know that I should use Gram-Schmidt but I am unsure of how to apply it.
I saw the examples and other problems dealing with multiple basis here but it did not make sense to me.

Please explain it to me in detail so that I can understand.

So I found a basis to be
$$u_{1}=(\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}},\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}},0,0)\\ u_{2}=(0,0,0,0)\\u_3=(\frac{4}{5\sqrt{\frac{41}{25}}},0,0,\frac{1}{\sqrt\frac{41}{25}})$$

Comment: Fina a basis of te subspace, then orthogonalise it (keep in mind that, for a sequence of linearly independent vectors $x_1, x_2,\cdots$, GS preserves $\operatorname{span}(x_1,\cdots, x_k)$ for all $k$).

Comment: You should have strong doubts about $u_2$ being a member of any basis ...

Answer (score 1):

As a first step find a "simple" basis that is

- $v_1=\left(2,1,0,0\right)$
- $v_2=\left(0,0,4,3\right)$
- $v_3=\left(4,0,0,1\right)$

and, we are lucky, $v_1$ and $v_2$ are othogonal, then we need to orthogonalize $v_3$ with respect to $v_1$ and $v_2$ and finally normalize the three orthogonal vectors.

Refer also to the related

- [Gram-Schmidt orthogonality](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2968004/505767)

---

Notably we can find the orthogonal component of $v_3$ by

$$w_3=v_3-\frac{v_1^Tw_3}{v_1^Tv_1}v_1-\frac{v_2^Tw_3}{v_2^Tv_2}v_2$$

and then normalize by

$$u_1=\frac{v_1}{\sqrt{v_1^Tv_1}}\quad u_2=\frac{v_2}{\sqrt{v_2^Tv_2}}\quad u_3=\frac{w_3}{\sqrt{w_3^Tw_3}}$$

Comment: How did you end up with those three basis?

Comment: @CapKoko The fors one is obtained by $x_3=x_4=0 \implies x_1=2x_2$, the second one by $x_1=x_2=0 \implies 3x_3=4x_4$ and the third one by $x_2=x_3=0$. In this way we are sure that we obian a basis.

Comment: That makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: would you check my answer for this question?

Comment: Yes of course! Where can I find that?

Comment: I just edited my question. Although I am not confident with my answer as u3 is a mess.
and u2 is not a basis since it's (0,0,0,0)

Comment: @CapKoko $v_1$ and $v_2$ are ok. You only need to orthogonalize $v_3$. Take a look to teh link I've given.

Comment: is the answer (4/5,-8/5,-12/25,16/25)?

Comment: @CapKoko I'll add some more hint asap